# Random variable on dyadic rationals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have measurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $(\Re, \mathcal{B})$, with X a measurable map: $\Omega \rightarrow \Re$; how do I know that $X$ is a random variable if $\{X \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all the dyadic rational numbers $x = \frac{m}{2^{k}}$ for $m, k \in Z$?

It would seem to me that for $X$ to be a random variable, we would need to ensure that there exists a measure $P$ such that $P(\Omega)=1$...

Answer (score 0):

Here the question has nothing to do with the notion of measure, but rather with that of measurability. Normally, the official definition of measurable is that for all $B\in\mathcal B$, $\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X\in B\right\}\in\mathcal F$.

Since the Borel sets may not have a nice form, it would be convenient to have to do the test $\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X\in B\right\}\in\mathcal F$ for sets $B$ in a small collection of sets than $\mathcal B$. Probably you are already aware that it suffice to do it for intervals of the form $(-\infty,x]$, $x\in\mathbb R$. Here, the point is that we can even work with a smaller class.

Here, we have to prove that for all $x$, there exists a non-increasing sequence of dyadics $(d_i)$ such that $(-\infty,x]=\bigcup_{i\geqslant 1}(-\infty,d_i]$.